# Trouble finding ViewModel property from ListView

Tags: binding, viewmodel

I have a rather complicated data binding template and I'm not able to find away back to my **ViewModel** to access a property and command.

This is how my **xaml** is set up from *Top* to *Bottom* as its layout:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChapterReferencesTemplate">
<StackPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Chapter Reference "/>
        <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=Chapter}" />
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Total Reference Verses "/>
        <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=Verses}" />
    </DockPanel>
    <ListView Name="VerseReferencesListView" Height="200"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VerseReferences}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentVerseReference, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:CreateWritingsViewModel}}}"
            AlternationCount="2"
            BorderThickness="0"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="xmlNamespace List" >
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Header="Verse" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Verse}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Header="Query" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Query}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Actions">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button 
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LookupReferencesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type src:CreateWritingsViewModel}}}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                Template="{StaticResource AddButtonTemplate}"  Cursor="Hand" Width="30"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="WritingsReferenceTemplate">

<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Hebrew}">
        <StackPanel Margin="5 10 5 0">
            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Writings of "/>
                    <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=Writings}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Total Reference Chapters : "/>
                    <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=Chapters}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Total Reference Verses : "/>
                    <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=Verses}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="Query for Writing : "/>
                    <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=QueryWriting}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="Query for Chapters : "/>
                    <AccessText Text="{Binding Path=QueryChapters}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel Margin="0 5 0 0">
                <GroupBox Header="Chapter References">
                    <Expander>
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="200">
                            <HeaderedItemsControl
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChapterReferencesTemplate}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChapterReferences}"
                                Margin="10,0,0,0" />

                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Expander>
                </GroupBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

```
<GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="CREATE REFERENCES">
<ListBox 
    Name="ReferenceListBox" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WritingsReferenceTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=odsDocumentsService.WritingsReferenceItems}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
</ListBox>
```

In my **HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChapterReferencesTemplate"** as you can see I'm already binding to **ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VerseReferences}"** but I also need to bind to my **ViewModel's** *CurrentVerseReference* for the **SelectedItem** property of the **ListView**.

Same for my **Button Command** to my **ViewModel's** *LookupReferencesCommand*.  All the data is coming from bindings to a *object class* that contains a **ObservableCollection** (*ChapterReferences*, *VerseReferences*)   So far I'm having no success in getting this to work and would appreciate your help very much.

Thanks!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the right properties to use to get this to work.  But, I need to do some reading to find out more about these property settings. For my **SelectedItem** I had to do this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentVerseReference, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
```

And for my **Button** *Command* and *CommandParameter* I had to do this and this is where I need to do more reading to understand how this worked:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LookupReferencesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, AncestorLevel=2, Mode=FindAncestor}}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentVerseReference, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, AncestorLevel=2, Mode=FindAncestor}}" 
                                        Template="{StaticResource AddButtonTemplate}"  Cursor="Hand" Width="30"/>
```

Its the **AncestorLevel** I don't understand.  I'm assuming its because I have the **Button** *control* at the second level of the **ListView**?